# Android: Add a drawable image to users phone remotley

Tags: android

I have a list of videos being shown. The user selects the video from a list of categories. From time to time I may have to add new categories (which would mean they would need a image downloaded and shown on there phone.

I was going to load the image on s3 and have the app check for new categories on startup then download if there is a new one.

Is this possible to automatically download and add a drawable or do I have to create an update every time I want to add a category.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: yes it is possible to load image from server (s3), you don't need to update app to do that

Comment: @hakim Thanks for your response, I mean save the image to the drawables folder or similar so that the user can the select that image in a recyclerview without being online.

Comment: I don't think that possible, since when an android app is packaged as apk it will be signed, changing the value inside apk need to re-sign the apk, and that not possible to be done inside mobile device

Comment: Ok, thank you appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to add files into drawable after the apk is built. Instead you can download the files and store into [device storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Like sdcard.